# invalid client when POSTing JSON to get OAuth token

Tags: ordercloud

I am using perl to POST a JSON object to fetch an Oauth token but am getting an "invalid_client" response. (I checked, and it doesn't look like I have a Client Secret set up.) I'm following the sandbox tutorial/walkthrough but am stuck at this point. Here are the relevant details (redacted):

```
url: 'https://sandboxapi.ordercloud.io/oauth/token'
JSON data
{
    client_id:  "XXXX",
    grant_type: "password",
    username:   "admin01",
    password:   "XXXX",
    scope:      "CatalogAdmin BuyerReader MeAdmin InventoryAdmin PasswordReset OrderAdmin PriceScheduleAdmin ProductAdmin ProductAssignmentAdmin ShipmentAdmin"
}
Headers: Content-Type   => 'application/json', Content => [JSON above]
```

I'm not sure if I have the url correct or if I have all necessary headers. I'm guessing the SDK abstracts a lot of that stuff but I'm not using it.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for authentication calls to OrderCloud. You can read more about authentication [here](https://ordercloud.io/knowledge-base/authentication).